# Given an array of usernames, how do I retrieve only their details from a Model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Lets say I want to retrieve a user with a username `$username`, normally I will do `Model::where('username',$username)->first();` Now, how should I do in order to get all the users given an array of usernames? Like `$users = ['enock', 'Erick','Simon'];`?

I have tried `whereIn` like `Model::whereIn('username', $users)->get()` but this returns the details of the first username alone and not the others yet I want all the users to be returned.

Comment: Show your full code, Or it might be you have only one match in DB?

Comment: $usernames = ["simon"," Yonetim"];
$users= User::whereIn('username', $usernames)->get(); return $users;            response: [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "username"Simon"
    }
]

Comment: All those users are in the database

Answer (score 0):

I had space before the second username " Yonetim"

```
   $usernames = ["Simon"," Yonetim"];
   $users= User::whereIn('username', $usernames)->get();
   return $users;
```

So this is still the correct way of doing it `Model::whereIn('username', $usernames)->get();`